# In java, how to check if a string contains any other characters except certain characters

Tags: java, string

I need a solution in Java to know if a string has any other characters except the three characters `*`, `.`, and `\n`.

Comment: show us what have you tried and post your error we may be happy to help you

Comment: Take a look at [matches(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))

Comment: Yes I am looking for a regx, and I tried with it. Sorry if my question was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

A simple regular expression should do it:

```
boolean hasOtherChars = !myString.matches("[\\*\\.\n]*");
```

Comment: The answer is always true here, if I pass *.\n.. or *.\n..$. However, I want false for the first input and true for the second input or vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

The following regexp will match any character which is not `*`, `.` or `\n`.

```
[^\*\.\n]+
```

Note that `+` is important here, as it will match **one or more** characters that are not `*`, `.` or `\n`.

The following code uses that regexp :

```
private boolean containsForbiddenChar(String input) {
    return Pattern.matches("[^\\*\\.\\n]+", input);
}
```

Comment: The answer is always true here, if I pass *.\n.. or *.\n..$. However, I want false for the first input and true for the second input or vise versa.